# 100% width flex horizontal list with justify-content:space-evenly, how to put bullets centered in spaces?

Tags: html, css, list, flexbox

I have an horizontal navigation bar, which is a UL list with a LI for each menu item, which has `display:flex` and `justify-content:space-evenly`

I can't fix the UL width, it should be as wide as its container, and I don't know the number of the items either.

How can I, by means of pure css and without adding tags in the html, put bullets always exactly in the middle of free space between items?

Comment: Post the current code please.

Comment: Two point answer to your question: 1. You should always show us some code so that everyone else can check and help you out.  2. It is not possible only with css and html to get a bullet point always at center. The reason being, everytime a new list item is added to ul, the space between li's will reduce and we need to manually adjust the position of bullet points in this case using pseudo elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build something to that effect by using after pseudo elements of the li elements for bullets and `display: contents;` to treat them as direct children of the ul-container which means they are put exactly in the middle of the real items. However this only works if there is only one "real" child inside the individual li elements (the a element in my example below)

```css
ul {
display: flex;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
justify-content:space-evenly;
align-items: center;
}

li {
display: contents;
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
}

li:not(:last-child):after {
content: "";
width: 5px;
height: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: currentcolor;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Point 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Point 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Point 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Point 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed! I'll go and study the display:content property value, since it's totally new for me...